# Software to quickly change WiFi power

Tags: windows, gratis, power-management

Can anyone recommend [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) software to quickly increase/decrease WiFi power?

Currently, the way to perform this task involves lengthy steps:

1. Open *Control Panel*.
2. Select *Power Options* or *Hardware and Sound* > *Power Options*.
3. Select *Change plan settings*.
4. Select *Change advanced power settings*.
5. Select *Wireless Adapter Settings*.
6. Open *Power Saving Mode*.
7. Change the *Power Saving Mode*.

Software either with a GUI or a basic Command Line Interface (CLI) is acceptable.

Comment: macro recorder?

Answer (score 1):

You already have it as a part of Windows - there is a command line tool called `powercfg` that allows you to do most/all of the things that the control panel does.

The easiest way to use it is to use the GUI to come up with some named power plans for your standard scenarios, then you can use `powercfg /L` to list out the GUID for the named plans and `powercfg /S <guid_for_desired_plan>` to set the one you need - on my system:

`powercfg /S 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c`

would put me in `High Performance` mode.

Obviously, you could create batch files or powershell scripts for the ones that you need and even attach them to shortcuts on the desktop.

It is also possible to override individual settings in the current plan with the same tool.

Full details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options

Comment: Steve, do you know of any way to use `powercfg` to change the WiFi power setting for the current power plan?  I was not able to find it in the docs.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - Run `POWERCFG /QUERY` look for the ID for Wireless Adapter Settings and for the desired Power Settings then you can use  /SETACVALUEINDEX or  /SETDCVALUEINDEX to override.

Comment: If I understand correctly, using /SETACVALUEINDEX or /SETDCVALUEINDEX will only work when the GUID of a power plan is specified.  IOW, it won't automatically work on the *current* power plan.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Yes you have to specify which plan, current is marked with an asterisk on the output of `powercfg /L` or use `powercfg /GETACTIVESCHEME`